# When Logic App Component Title Changes, Expression/JavaScript Fails

Tags: azure-logic-apps

When I need to use the ID of a component in expressions (or in a JavaScript code), I need to write the ID manually. And then if there is a change on this ID, the expression fails because the id in the expression does not get updated automatically.

Is there any way to use IDs without a need for manual intervention in the expression?

Case 1:

[image]

Case 2:

[image]

Comment: As your question got answered in [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/471715/index.html). Please refer to the solution from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action names (rather the snake case versions of them) are used to identify which action is being referred to. Since this is derived from the name of the action, the change needs to be made across the workflow.

One way to better make this kind of change is using the `Code View` of the Logic App, where you can use `Ctrl + D` to multiselect the name of the action and make changes in one shot.

Another way would be to leverage [variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-create-variables-store-values) which allow you to store values in named variables which you can control. This would however mean having extra actions to initialize these variables.

*Originally posted on [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/471715/when-logic-app-component-title-changes-expressionj.html)*

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. CTRL+D is a nice way to locate the instances even though it doesn't save us from manual change. As for the second part, using variables has nothing to do with the issue of updating control names because you can't use variables for control names.

Comment: Yes. The variables that I've mentioned are to store the required tokens, not the control names.